# Как отправить сообщение пользователя другому пользователю в aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Всем привет, хочу сделать бота автоответчика. (пользователь нажимает /start и на мой аккаунт приходит заявка что человек хочет с нами связаться, где указан его username)

Но не пойму как выполнить отправку заявки на мой аккаунт

код ниже, благодарю за обратную связь!

```
from aiogram import Dispatcher, Bot, types, executor
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, ReplyKeyboardRemove, KeyboardButton


token = "токен бота"

bot = Bot(token)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

kb = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
kb1 = KeyboardButton("/start")

kb.add(kb1)


@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Спасибо за оставленую заявку, в скором времени мы с вами свяжемся",
                         reply_markup=kb)
```

Comment: Возможный дубль: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1318464/418625

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно в вашей функции также сделать отправку самому себе:
bot.send_message({ваш айди}, {айди человека который отправил заявку})
Айди человека можно взять с помощью такой конструкции:
message.from_user.id

```
    @dp.message_handler(commands=['get'])
    async def get(msg: types.Message):
        await msg.answer('Спасибо за заявку')
        await bot.send_message(329813348, msg.from_user.id)
```

Comment: Немного недопонимаю, можете пожалуйста подробнее написать?

Answer (score 0):

**Немного расширю ответ @Vlad, с его позволения**

Чтобы отправить заявку в свой аккаунт, вы можете использовать метод `send_message`, предоставляемый библиотекой `alogram`, чтобы отправить сообщение в свою собственную учетную запись.

Чтобы сделать это, вам нужно сначала получить `chat_id` вашей собственной учетной записи Telegram. Вы можете сделать это, отправив сообщение своему боту, а затем проверив `message.chat.id` атрибут сообщения, которое получает ваш бот.

Как только вы получите свой собственный идентификатор `chat_id`, вы можете использовать метод `send_message`, чтобы отправить сообщение самому себе, например:

```py
@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message):
    # Obtain the user's username from the message
    username = message.from_user.username
    
    # Send a message to yourself with the user's username
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=<your chat_id>, text=f"Пользователь с именем {username} хочет связаться с вами.")
    
    # Send a reply message to the user
    await message.answer("Спасибо за оставленную заявку, в скором времени мы с вами свяжемся.", reply_markup=kb)
```

Обязательно замените `<your chat_id>` на ваш собственный идентификатор чата, который вы можете получить, отправив сообщение своему боту и проверив `message.chat.id` атрибут сообщения.